# Handling AWS subnet failure for VPN endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, tinc

I've built a VPN endpoint using tinc in one aws subnet:-

```
[ eu-west-1a tinc ]------
   |                    |
[ us dc] -- ipsec -- [ uk dc ]
```

Some failure conditions are handled by tincs meshing:-

```
[ eu-west-1a tinc ]------
   |                    |
   ^                    x
   |                    |
[ us dc] -<- ipsec -- [ uk dc ]

[ eu-west-1a tinc ]------
   |                    |
   x                    ^
   |                    |
[ us dc] ->- ipsec -- [ uk dc ]
```

---

So as an option for tinc failures in aws I could build another tinc box in a different subnet and use keepalived to move the eni between the two servers but I can't find any good docs on how to detect subnet failure. What happens to keepalived in the event that the link between subnet a and b goes down i.e how is split brain handled?

```
   [ eu-west-1a tinc ]--keepalived---[ eu-west-1b tinc ]
                          |                  
                         vip                     
                          |                    
                      [ uk dc ]
```

Another option is to run 2 tincs and have some sort of 'witness' service that decides which should be live and updates the routing table in the aws vpc. I can't find any sort of offical docs on how to build a witness service in aws, could you use aws lambda for instance? I am aware of the aws vpn services though.